# Finding the difference between new value and old value for amount

Tags: reporting, formula-field, data

I have a basic opportunity field history report that's filtered so I'm only looking at changes in Amount. I want a column that shows me the difference between the new value and the old value. I tried creating a summary formula as follows:

`NEWVAL:UNIQUE - OLDVAL:UNIQUE`

I only included `unique` because without it, Salesforce keeps telling me there are no such fields as `newval` or `oldval`, though they do show up with "unique" at the end. I also tried using the `value()` function before each field, but that didn't work.

Right now, nothing shows up in that column. I'm guessing it's got to do with me including `unique`, but I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because xxxHistory records use type Object for fields OldValue and NewValue, operations on those fields can't be done using the OOB tools (i.e. they could be checkboxes or strings)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the "**Historical Trending**" standard salesforce setting. You can easily build reports based on historical values of any field and compare,track the changes.

Once you build a historical trending report you can compare current values with the any historical value(for example 1 week ago, 1 month ago, first day this month...). It is very flexible.

Kindly refer this link which exactly matches your requirement :- [Diff b/w Old value and new value](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8S0RSAV)

Watch Your Pipeline Change Over Time

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_track_pipeline_value.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Set Up Historical Trend Reporting

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_historical_setup.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Ranjain This doesn't get my quite where I need to be. I should have specified that I'm trying to exclude all new pipeline and only look where the Amount was previously known and has been updated.